# Asp.Net .Net 5 Lambda LINQ get the number of users in a particular role

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, .net-5

I am using Asp.Net .Net5 with Entity framework 5. I'm trying to work out the number of basic users. The table aspnetuser is connected to aspnetRoles through a many to many relationship by aspnetuserRoles link table.

I have 3 tables

1. aspnetuser
2. aspnetroles
3. aspnetuserRoles  = link table

   ```
   public int GetNumberOfActiveBasicUsers()
   {
       var users = _context.Users
           .Where(u => u.IsEnabled == true)
           .Where(u => u.UserName != "AdminUser")
           .Include(r => r.UserRoles)
           .ThenInclude(r => r.Role)

           //not sure what to put here


           .Count();  

        return users;
    }
   ```

aspnetuser table

```
id | username
--------------
1  | Jim
2  | Harry
3  | James
3  | Susan
```

aspnetRoles

```
id | name
----------
1  | admin
2  | standard
3  | Basic
```

aspnetuserRoles  // link table

```
userId | roleId
----------------
   1   |   1
   2   |   2
   3   |   3
   4   |   3
```

The code should return back with a value of 2 as there are 2 basic users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
return _context.UserRoles
        .Where(ur => ur.User.IsEnabled && ur.Role.Name== "Basic")
        .Count();
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I've been developing for 2 years and I still struggle with LINQ, I've looked on Microsoft docs but I still struggle. Where did you learn linq?

Comment: You are welcome! Try this https://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx it helps me a lot and worth every cent if you buy the full version.